# WordPress .htaccess security code breaks Font Awesome icon site-wide

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security

I have written this security code in a separate .htaccess file in the directory of **wp-content/**.htaccess  and it's broke Font Awesome icon site-wide. Can anyone show me how to solve it?
Thanks.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

I have tried removing the in-code text called "png" and it worked but I want to keep it as it provides security.

Comment: If you tell your web server not to serve the assets you need from plugins (all of which live in wp_content) it won't serve those assets. WordPress needs to be able to serve those files, and core does a decent job of securely maintaining `.htaccess`  files. Get rid of the file you showed us and let WordPress do its job.

Comment: @O. Jones Thanks for your comment and instruction. 
Sorry that I'm going to ask another question, so as you said to delete this .htaccess file and rely only on the root .htaccess then should I put that code in root .htaccess?

Comment: "removing the in-code text called "png" and it worked" - What do you mean exactly by that? If you removed `png` from the regex alternation then it would make the rule _more_ restrictive, not less. (Unless you literally only removed the letters `png` from that regex?!) (But why "png"?) If you are using Font Awesome then you obviously also need to allow access to the **font files**. (NB: `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` directives are deprecated Apache 2.2 directives. On Apache 2.4 you should be using `Require`.)

Comment: Sitewide `.htaccess` files must handled by WordPress if you want permalinks to work. Security is front-of-mind for the people who develop WordPress, and they're trustworthy. My suggestion to site owners: don't do anything with any `.htaccess` file, but rather let WordPress do it. If you need more security use one of the security plugins.  You might [edit] your question to explain why you think you need the extra `.htaccess` file -- to explain the threat you're trying to guard against.

Comment: Thanks, As my client site have been attacked multiple times, and the way hackers injected codes and uploaded files. I thought I must secure the wp-content and wp-content/upload folders.

Ok, I am using a "Wordfence Free License" now as the client doesn't wanna pay for it. And gonna remove those separate .htaccess files.